# Loading spinner is not hiding after response is retrieved in component

Tags: angular, forms, observable

I have an Angular app that includes an authentication module. I am currently working on the registration component and would like to include a loading spinner that by default is hidden then displays while waiting for the data to return.

For this use case I would like the spinner to start after the form is submitted and hide once the response is received from the observable.

Currently, everything works except the spinner doesn't hide once the response is received. I can even see my flag `isLoading` change to `false` but the spinner just keeps spinning.

Here is my component code for the registration:
`registration.component.ts`

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '@modules/auth/services';

@Component({
    selector: 'sb-register',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    templateUrl: './register.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['register.component.scss'],
})
export class RegisterComponent {
    isLoading = false;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
    // ngOnInit() {}
    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        if (!form.valid) {
            return;
        }
        const firstName = form.value.firstName;
        const lastName = form.value.lastName;
        const email = form.value.email;
        const password = form.value.password;

        this.isLoading = true;
        this.authService.signup(firstName, lastName, email, password).subscribe(
            resData => {
                console.log(resData);
                this.isLoading = false;
                console.log(this.isLoading);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
        );

        form.reset();
    }
}
```

and here is my corresponding template:
`registration.component.html`

```
<sb-layout-auth>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="card shadow-lg border-0 rounded-lg mt-5">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="text-center font-weight-light my-4">Create Account</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div *ngIf="isLoading"  style="text-align: center;">
                        <sb-loading-spinner></sb-loading-spinner>
                    </div>
                        <form #authForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(authForm)" *ngIf="!isLoading">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" for="inputFirstName">First
                                            Name</label>
                                            <input 
                                                class="form-control py-4" 
                                                id="firstName" 
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Enter first name" 
                                                ngModel
                                                name="firstName"
                                                required
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" for="inputLastName">Last
                                            Name</label>
                                            <input 
                                                class="form-control py-4" 
                                                id="lastName" 
                                                type="text"
                                                placeholder="Enter last name" 
                                                ngModel
                                                name="lastName"
                                                required
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1"
                                    for="inputEmailAddress">Email</label>
                                    <input 
                                        class="form-control py-4"
                                        type="email" 
                                        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                                        placeholder="Enter email address" 
                                        type="email"
                                        id="email"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        ngModel
                                        name="email"
                                        required
                                        email
                                    />
                                </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1"
                                            for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                            <input 
                                            class="form-control py-4"         
                                            type="password" 
                                            placeholder="password" 
                                            type="password"
                                            id="password"
                                            ngModel
                                            name="password"
                                            required
                                            minlength="6"
                                            placeholder="Enter password"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" for="inputConfirmPassword">Confirm
                                            Password</label>
                                            <input 
                                                class="form-control py-4"         
                                                type="password" 
                                                placeholder="Confirm password" 
                                                type="password"
                                                id="confirm_password"
                                                ngModel
                                                name="confirm_password"
                                                required
                                                minlength="6"
                                                placeholder="Enter password" 
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mt-4 mb-0">
                                <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" -->
                            <button
                                class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                                type="submit"
                                [disabled]="!authForm.valid"
                            >Create Account
                            </button>
                                    <!-- routerLink="/dashboard">Create Account</a></div> -->
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                        <div class="small"><a routerLink="/auth/login">Have an account? Go to login</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</sb-layout-auth>
```

Here is my auth service as well that generates the observable:
`auth.service.ts`
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

```
interface AuthResponseData {
    status: string,
    res: string,
    message: string
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    signup(firstName: string, lastName: string, email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>(
            'http://localhost:5000/v1/auth/register',
            {
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                email: email,
                password: password
            }
        );
    }

    login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>(
            'http://localhost:5000/v1/auth/login',
            {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is using On Push change detection, which means change detection will only run when Inputs change or an event was triggered. Setting `loading` inside the subscription handler wont cause a change detection cycle. You could inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `markForCheck()` after setting loading to force a check.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the `On Push change detection` and it works now.